# What does a bitwise shift in a C enum definition do?

Tags: c, enums, bit-shift

I'm new to C and wanted to know, what does a bitwise shift 1 << 9 in an enum definition do in this case below:

```
static enum {
    DEAD, LIVE
} state[1 << 9];
```

Comment: It is not part of the enum definition; it is part of the *variable* definition. Hint: what would the `[]` indicate here if you were declaring any *other* sort of variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code defines a `static` array of values of an unnamed `enum` with 2 values `DEAD` (0) or `LIVE` (1). The number of elements for this array is specified as `1 << 9` (512).

It would be more readable to separate these as

```
enum status { DEAD, LIVE };
static enum status state[1 << 9];
```

Note also that the size of this enum type is implementation specific. If compactness is an issue, you should use an array of `unsigned char`, or use a bitwise representation but you would need to hand code it as the C language does not have built-in support for arrays of bits:

```
enum { DEAD = 0, LIVE = 1 };
static unsigned char state[1 << 9];
```

Comment: Ah thank you. This seems to explain it well. As @Karl Knechtel said it is part of the variable definition. I was confused thinking it was part of the enum's definition, which doesn't have a name when coded in the way in my example.

Answer (score 6):

The expression `1<<9` is the same as 2<sup>9</sup>, which is 512.

So an array of 512 enums is declared.

Comment: Ah god.. so simple. Thanks!